# Solving problems with similar and congruent triangles

Tags: geometry

I don't understand the following step:

$CD = x - \frac{x}y$

$CD = \frac{y-1}{y}x$

This is from a step in an answer to a problem on Khan Academy relating to figuring out the sides of similar triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows by distributivity:

$$\begin{align}x-\frac{x}{y}&=\Big(1-\frac{1}{y}\Big)x \\
&=\Big(\frac{y}{y}-\frac{1}{y}\Big)x \\
&=\frac{y-1}{y}x\end{align}$$

Comment: @Jeremy Did that answer your question? :)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot Shaun :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Jeremy. Don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the tick! :)